# $Ker (f)$ is finite, then $G$ is finite.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$, $f: G → G$ a homomorphism for which there is a natural $n> 1$ such that $f^n (G)$ = `{e}.`

i. Prove that if $Ker (f)$ is finite, then $G$ is finite.

ii. Prove that if $[G: f (G)]$ is finite, then $G$ is finite

Comment: Whoa. Weird rapid unclear what you're asking close vote. Did the person even read the question?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What does $f^n(G)$ trivial tell you about a relationship with the kernel and the image?

Comment: Hint:  look first at $f^2$.  Given that $Ker(f)$ is finite, can you conclude anything about $Ker(f^2)$?

Comment: 1) Suppose that G is infinite . Note that $ Im (f^{n
-1})\subset(f)$. On the other hand , for the first isomorphism
theorem $ \frac{G}{ker(f^{n -1})}\cong Im (f^{n -1})$ and by
Lagrange theorem

$\infty= [G:ker(f^{n-1})]|ker(f^{n-1})|$

implying that  $|ker(f^{n-1})|=\infty$ ...

of here not as continue to fall